# Thinking sphinx with rails - order by association column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, full-text-search, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Is there an ability to order search results by association column in thinking sphinx?

I have index defined as follows:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :demand, :with => :active_record, :delta => true do
  indexes client(:name), as: :client, sortable: true
  has(created_at, updated_at, client_id)
end
```

The search is performed in controller:

```
Demand.search(params[:query], order: "#{params[:sort]} #{params[:direction].try(:upcase)}")
```

The value of `params[order]` is `"client.name"`, `params[:direction]` is either `"asc"` or `"desc"`

Here is the query that is generated by sphinx:

```
SELECT * FROM `demand_core`, `demand_delta` WHERE MATCH('Test_client @sphinx_internal_class_name (Demand)') AND sphinx_deleted = 0 ORDER BY client.name DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

When I perform search I get the following error:

```
ThinkingSphinx::SyntaxError - sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected CONST_FLOAT, expecting $end near '.name DESC LIMIT 0, 20; SHOW META':
```

I've been searching for a while for the solution but couldn't find one. So the question is how can i apply ordering in sphinx after i perform the search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the field/attribute names when sorting - so in your situation, it should be `client`, not `client.name`. Hopefully it's not too tricky to change what params[:sort] value is passed through to the controller.

Comment: Yay! That worked, thanks a lot. Perhaps you should extend you answer so that it becomes obvious how to solve that issue.